# out of memory issue when backup data using php

Tags: php, yii

i used yii module for backup sql database, i have notice error like this :
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 295436288) (tried to allocate 225446869 bytes)

i was browsing and error above because my database too large. any solution that i can do here ? i read some article that i can use flush() function for reduce memory usage.

```
<?php
/**
  * Backup
  *
  * Yii module to backup, restore databse
  *
  * @version 1.0
  * @author Shiv Charan Panjeta <shiv@toxsl.com>   <shivcharan.panjeta@outlook.com>
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
 {

/**
 * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
 * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
 */
public $layout='//layouts/column2';

/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
    array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                    'actions'=>array('create1'),
                    'users'=>array('*'),
    ),
    array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                    'actions'=>array(),
                    'users'=>array('@'),
    ), 
    array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                    'actions'=>array('admin','delete','clean','index','view','create','upload', 'download','restore'),
                    'users'=>array('admin'),
    ),
    array('deny',  // deny all users
                    'users'=>array('*'),
    ),
    );
}


public $tables = array();
public $fp ;
public $file_name;
public $_path = null;
public $back_temp_file = 'db_backup_';

protected function getPath()
{
    if ( isset ($this->module->path )) $this->_path = $this->module->path;
    else $this->_path = Yii::app()->basePath .'/../_backup/';

    if ( !file_exists($this->_path ))
    {
        mkdir($this->_path );
        chmod($this->_path, '777');
    }
    return $this->_path;
}
public function execSqlFile($sqlFile)
{
    $message = "ok";

    if ( file_exists($sqlFile))
    {
        $sqlArray = file_get_contents($sqlFile);

        $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlArray);
        try {
            $cmd->execute();
        }
        catch(CDbException $e)
        {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
    return $message;
}
public function getColumns($tableName)
{
    $sql = 'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$tableName;
    $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $table = $cmd->queryRow();

    $create_query = $table['Create Table'] . ';';

    $create_query  = preg_replace('/^CREATE TABLE/', 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS', $create_query);
    //$create_query = preg_replace('/AUTO_INCREMENT\s*=\s*([0-9])+/', '', $create_query);
    if ( $this->fp)
    {
        $this->writeComment('TABLE `'. addslashes ($tableName) .'`');
        $final = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' .addslashes($tableName) . '`;'.PHP_EOL. $create_query .PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
        fwrite ( $this->fp, $final );
    }
    else
    {
        $this->tables[$tableName]['create'] = $create_query;
        return $create_query;
    }
}

public function getData($tableName)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tableName;
    $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $dataReader = $cmd->query();

    $data_string = '';

    foreach($dataReader as $data)
    {
        $itemNames = array_keys($data);
        $itemNames = array_map("addslashes", $itemNames);
        $items = join('`,`', $itemNames);
        $itemValues = array_values($data);
        $itemValues = array_map("addslashes", $itemValues);
        $valueString = join("','", $itemValues);
        $valueString = "('" . $valueString . "'),";
        $values ="\n" . $valueString;
        if ($values != "")
        {
            $data_string .= "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (`$items`) VALUES" . rtrim($values, ",") . ";" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    if ( $data_string == '')
    return null;

    if ( $this->fp)
    {
        $this->writeComment('TABLE DATA '.$tableName);
        $final = $data_string.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
        fwrite ( $this->fp, $final );
    }
    else
    {
        $this->tables[$tableName]['data'] = $data_string;
        return $data_string;
    }
}
public function getTables($dbName = null)
{
    $sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
    $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $tables = $cmd->queryColumn();
    return $tables;
}
public function StartBackup($addcheck = true)
{
    $this->file_name =  $this->path . $this->back_temp_file . date('Y.m.d_H.i.s') . '.sql';

    $this->fp = fopen( $this->file_name, 'w+');

    if ( $this->fp == null )
    return false;
    fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );
    if ( $addcheck )
    {
        fwrite ( $this->fp,  'SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;' .PHP_EOL );
        fwrite ( $this->fp,  'START TRANSACTION;' .PHP_EOL );
        fwrite ( $this->fp,  'SET SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE = 1;'  .PHP_EOL );
    }
    fwrite ( $this->fp, 'SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;'.PHP_EOL );
    fwrite ( $this->fp, 'SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'.PHP_EOL );
    fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );
    $this->writeComment('START BACKUP');
    return true;
}
public function EndBackup($addcheck = true)
{
    fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );
    fwrite ( $this->fp, 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;'.PHP_EOL );
    fwrite ( $this->fp, 'SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;'.PHP_EOL );

    if ( $addcheck )
    {
        fwrite ( $this->fp,  'COMMIT;' .PHP_EOL );
    }
    fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );
    $this->writeComment('END BACKUP');
    fclose($this->fp);
    $this->fp = null;
}

public function writeComment($string)
{
    fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );
    fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- '.$string .PHP_EOL );
    fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );
}
public function actionCreate()
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $tables = $this->getTables();

    if(!$this->StartBackup())
    {
        //render error
        $this->render('create');
        return;
    }

    foreach($tables as $tableName)
    {
        $this->getColumns($tableName);
    }
    foreach($tables as $tableName)
    {
        $this->getData($tableName);
    }
    $this->EndBackup();

    $this->redirect(array('index'));
}
public function actionClean($redirect = true)
{
    $tables = $this->getTables();

    if(!$this->StartBackup())
    {
        //render error
        return;
    }

    foreach($tables as $tableName)
    {
        fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );
        fwrite ( $this->fp, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' .addslashes($tableName) . ';'.PHP_EOL );
        fwrite ( $this->fp, '-- -------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL );

    }
    $this->EndBackup();

    // logout so there is no problme later .
    Yii::app()->user->logout();

    $this->execSqlFile($this->file_name);
    unlink($this->file_name);
    if ( $redirect == true) $this->redirect(array('index'));
}
public function actionDelete($file = null)
{
    $this->updateMenuItems();
    if ( isset($file))
    {
        $sqlFile = $this->path . basename($file);
        if ( file_exists($sqlFile))
        unlink($sqlFile);
    }
    else throw new CHttpException(404, Yii::t('app', 'File not found'));
    $this->actionIndex();
}

public function actionDownload($file = null)
{
    $this->updateMenuItems();
    if ( isset($file))
    {
        $sqlFile = $this->path . basename($file);
        if ( file_exists($sqlFile))
        {
            $request = Yii::app()->getRequest();
            $request->sendFile(basename($sqlFile),file_get_contents($sqlFile));
        }
    }
    throw new CHttpException(404, Yii::t('app', 'File not found'));
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->updateMenuItems();
    $path = $this->path;

    $dataArray = array();

    $list_files = glob($path .'*.sql');
    if ($list_files )
    {
        $list = array_map('basename',$list_files);
        sort($list);


        foreach ( $list as $id=>$filename )
        {
            $columns = array();
            $columns['id'] = $id;
            $columns['name'] = basename ( $filename);
            $columns['size'] = floor(filesize ( $path. $filename)/ 1024) .' KB';
            $columns['create_time'] = date( DATE_RFC822, filectime($path .$filename) );
            $dataArray[] = $columns;
        }
    }
    $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($dataArray);
    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
}
public function actionSyncdown()
{
    $tables = $this->getTables();

    if(!$this->StartBackup())
    {
        //render error
        $this->render('create');
        return;
    }

    foreach($tables as $tableName)
    {
        $this->getColumns($tableName);
    }
    foreach($tables as $tableName)
    {
        $this->getData($tableName);
    }
    $this->EndBackup();
    $this->actionDownload(basename($this->file_name));
}

public function actionRestore($file = null)
{
    $this->updateMenuItems();
    $message = 'OK. Done';
    $sqlFile = $this->path . 'install.sql';
    if ( isset($file))
    {
        $sqlFile = $this->path . basename($file);
    }

    $this->execSqlFile($sqlFile);
    $this->render('restore',array('error'=>$message));
}

public function actionUpload()
{
    $model= new UploadForm('upload');
    if(isset($_POST['UploadForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['UploadForm'];
        $model->upload_file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'upload_file');
        if($model->upload_file->saveAs($this->path . $model->upload_file))
        {
            // redirect to success page
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }

    $this->render('upload',array('model'=>$model));
}

protected function updateMenuItems($model = null)
{
    // create static model if model is null
    if ( $model == null ) $model=new UploadForm('install');

    switch( $this->action->id)
    {
        case 'restore':
            {
                $this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'View Site') , 'url'=>Yii::app()->HomeUrl);
            }
        case 'create':
            {
                $this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'List Backup') . ' ' . $model->label(2), 'url'=>array('index'));
            }
            break;
        case 'upload':
            {
                $this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Create Backup') . ' ' . $model->label(), 'url'=>array('create'));
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                $this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'List Backup') . ' ' . $model->label(2), 'url'=>array('index'));
                $this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Create Backup') . ' ' . $model->label(), 'url'=>array('create'));
                //$this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Upload Backup') . ' ' . $model->label(), 'url'=>array('upload'));
                //$this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Restore Backup') . ' ' . $model->label(), 'url'=>array('restore'));
                //$this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Clean Database') . ' ' . $model->label(), 'url'=>array('clean'));
                //$this->menu[] = array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'View Site') , 'url'=>Yii::app()->HomeUrl);
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you call this via CGI or CLI? You could increase the value of  `memory_limit` in your php.ini.

Comment: i have set memory_limit on php.ini 2047M. and still get notice like that. i call that class on yii backup module...

Comment: Then maybe dump your database with a tool like `mysqldump` and not with PHP if your database is that big.

Comment: my project manager want to add feature for sql backup on web app. so what best solution is ? remove this feature ? create a limit function an alert when database too large? add more memory on server ? optimize the code? if you are in my position, what you choose?

Comment: Do your server have enough(2GB, as you tried to set) free memory(RAM).

Answer (score 0):

allocated 295436288 bytes , that's like 295MB.

As you said you set it to 2GB. You are either doing wrong in php.ini And maybe if code you are working on might have restriction or option to set memory usage.

and anyways, have you restarted server after php.ini changes.

new edit :

```
Do your server have enough(2GB, as you tried to set) free memory(RAM).
```

Comment: then, what value i must set memory_limit on php.ini ? i always restart server on every change.

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH are you on localhost , and what's framework , if any.

Comment: i think no, my free memory maybe just 1.1GB

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH then that's pretty much an answer. how you can allocated memory greater than what you have. you have 1.1G nad allocating 2G . try with 800M

Comment: i have change it into 800M, and still got error. and sql file is only 321832 KB,  (on my database is about 700MB)

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH , after changing to 800M whats new error

Comment: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 709099520) (tried to allocate 217357012 bytes)

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH awesome so finally allocation is working. though it's asking for more than 800M , it's your code. written bad. Use netbeans or something to debug and check for memory meter it has. and if it's not your code there might be a seperate memory limitation in that code checkout for that

Comment: it isnt my code, i just download a module on yii website an apply it into my app. and the bug is, when database too large, it show error like that